# how do i run quickfix examples?

Tags: c++, config, quickfix

I have installed QuickFix on my mac and am keen to understand the examples that come with it as described here http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/examples.html. The trouble is this documentation is very poor and gives no instructions on 1) which process to start first 2) how to start the 3 applications. Does anyone know where to find instructions for this? Here are my configurations, however when attempting to run the apps i see a "Configuration failed: No sessions defined for acceptor" on the ordermatch side:

executor.cfg:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
ReconnectInterval=5
SenderCompID=*
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=*
HeartBtInt=5
SocketAcceptPort=56156
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
TransportDataDictionary=/Users/asifshaikh/Downloads/quickfix/spec/FIX50.xml
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
FileStorePath=store
```

ordermatch.cfg

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=5
SenderCompID=SENDER
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=EXEC
HeartBtInt=5
SocketConnectPort=56156
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
TransportDataDictionary=/Users/asifshaikh/Downloads/quickfix/spec/FIX50.xml
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
FileLogPath=log
FileStorePath=store
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What command are you using to run them?  If memory serves, you need to supply the config file as a parameter.  Run the acceptor first (in FIX lingo, the acceptor is the server, the initiator is the client).

Comment: I run the executor first passing the config as a command like parameter, followed by the order match, again with a config as a parameter. The executor appears to start fine but the ordermatch gives me the following error: Configuration failed: No sessions defined for acceptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah!  I should have noticed this sooner.

Executor and OrderMatch are both server-side applications, so they won't talk to each other, as they are both defined as Acceptors.  When you run OrderMatch, it's an Acceptor, so it's looking for an Acceptor entry in your config (which configures an Initiator).

The TradeClient example app is an Initiator.  Use that instead with either Executor or OrderMatch.

Comment: thanks grant i have tradeclient and ordermatch working together, there is very little documentation on this stuff, can i be cheeky and message you if i have any questions?

Comment: I am seeing this message on the client side, any ideas? "Message Not Sent: Session Not Found"

Comment: I highly recommend joining the QF mailing list (which I am on).  The traffic is not too high, and you usually get an answer quickly.

Comment: I can't tell; I'd need more info.  Which code line it comes from, for one.  It's after login has succeeded, right?

Comment: finally figured it out, it was a config issue, it is very strange they did not document any of this, i am considering doing this and uploading it on the forum to save others the time i wasted